# Why "trace dependents" shortcut is not working in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I have found out that "Trace dependents" shortcut Ctrl+[ is not working on particular Excel installations. For example, my colleague's Excel 2010 does not recognize Ctrl+[ while this shortcut perfectly works for me. We have same notebooks, our Windows and Office versions were installed from the same corporate installation package and are absolutely identical.

My home computer version of Excel 2013 has this problem too - Ctrl+[ shortcut is not working.

I have tried to search for solution, but it seems that this shortcut is not widely used (although being extremely handy in my opinion) and I found no solution.

Could anyone advise how can I enable this shortcut at least in Excel 2013.

Comment: What Ribbon Tab is active when you touch *Ctrl + [* ??

Comment: I should explain that shortcut Ctrl+[ I am referring to does not put arrows showing which cells are dependent on this one, but it moves cursor to cells in the formula. For example, if you press Ctrl+[ on cell where formula is "SUM(D1:D6)" it will move selection to cells "D1:D6" rather than show arrows.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the data-cell and touch:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> then <kbd>m</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd>

as three separate keystrokes and you should create an arrow to the dependent formula-cell.

**EDIT#1:**

Starting with an empty worksheet, place **1** in **A1** and place the formula:

```
=A1
```

in cell **A2**.

If you click on the data-cell **A1** and touch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> you should jump to the formula-cell **A2**.

If you click on the formula-cell **A2** and touch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> you should jump back to the data-cell **A1**.

*(remember to start with an empty worksheet)*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. ALT-M-D shows the arrows (and actually is the shortcut to "Trace dependents" button in the ribbon) which is not the same as what Ctrl+[ is doing. Possibly, I should be using another description, because there no such button in the ribbon, which selects the cells in the formula.

Comment: @DenisAvdonin  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested, but nothing happens when I press Ctrl+[, I have tried both new empty workbook and existing workbook with lots of formulas.
This is the problem that I'm trying to find solution for - Ctrl+[ shortcut is not working.

Comment: @DenisAvdonin  Are **both** *Ctrl+]* and *Ctrl+[* not working ???

Comment: Yes, both of them are not working.

Comment: @DenisAvdonin  You are correct...it is quite strange....It works for me with *Excel 2007* under *Win 7*

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking that multiple Sheets are not selected in the Workbook (usually displayed near bottom of the interface). This condition is also indicated by “Group” appearing near the file name in Excel 2016. When a “Group” is selected, Trace Dependents is not available/grayed-out. 
 [Group selected:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwcPn.png)
[Single sheet only selected:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H37wW.png)

Answer (score -2):

This solved for me!

Save the file as 'Excel 97-2003 Workbook' and try Ctrl+[. If worked well, then save the file again as 'Excel Workbook'.

This solution is intended for people with the same issues in the future.